# Building Rcpp package with external C library on Windows

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am building a package with provides a wrapper around the cvode solver from the [SUNDIALS](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/sundials-software) ODE solving C library.

So far, I have been able to compile the package on my `OS X` machine by providing the source C files (taking inspiration from the `Makevars` from [RcppCAF](https://github.com/grantbrown/RcppCAF/blob/master/src/Makevars) package) and making the static library on the fly and linking against it. The `Makevars` file can be found at the link below

https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/blob/master/src/Makevars

Earlier I was linking against static libraries on the system but now since I am making the static library (`libsundials_all.a`) on the fly when compiling the package, I believe users who don't have SUNDIALS installed on their system (at least on `OS X`) should be able to use this package also (Am I correct in thinking this?). I have checked the package compiled in such a way is able to integrate the a test ODE. Also, When I run a `R CMD check` (using `Check` option on RStudio, with `--as-cran` option), I get success, i.e.,

```
R CMD check results
0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

However, I want users on Windows to be able to use this package, even if they don't have SUNDIALS installed on their machine, my questions are

1. Is this possible to do or Windows users need to have SUNDIALS installed?
2. Currently my `Makevars.win` is same as `Makevars`, so when I submit my package on R WinBuilder, I get the following message (which tells me that `make` is not able to find `ar`).

   `make: ar: Command not found`
   `make: *** [../inst/libsundials_all.a] Error 127`
   `Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.4.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.4.3/etc/i386/Makevars.site" -f "D:/RCompile/recent/R-3.4.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="Rcppsbmod.dll" ' had status 2`
   `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcppsbmod'`
   `* removing 'd:/RCompile/CRANguest/R-release/lib/Rcppsbmod'`
   `In R CMD INSTALL`

Some searching revealed that `RTools` might not have `ar`,[here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) but I don't think I am clear about what I should be doing to compile this package on Windows. I have looked a few `Makevars.win` files, but most of them are similar to `Makevars`. I feel I need to make a `.dll` (similar to `libsundials_all.a`, but I am not sure how to go about it at all.

Any suggestion here about how I can compile this package on Windows will be much appreciated!

Also, just for my curiosity, I often find code such (e.g., in `Makevars.in` of `rcppgsl`)

```
GSL_LIBS   = @GSL_LIBS@
```

I am not sure what `@GSL_LIBS@` means and `make` tutorials didn't have this syntax either. Any explanation of this code will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try eg [this post](http://rcpp-devel.r-forge.r-project.narkive.com/pxsStla7/configuring-gsl-headers-and-library-for-rcppgsl-use-on-windows).  It is a CRAN-Windows convention.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I will take a look at the link you have mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, using the _environment variable_ `GSL_LIBS` is the windows convention.  Using `@GSL_LIBS` designates `autoconf`, ie the value will get filled in (on Linux, Unix, macOS, ...) by the `configure` script. I explained that in a few places too; you can just follow package RcppGSL or, easier, other packages using RcppGSL -- eg my small RcppZiggurat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build a static library on Windows during package installation. I am doing that in the experimental [windows branch of dqmagic](https://github.com/daqana/dqmagic/tree/windows/src):

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I./libmagic -I./libgnurx -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
PKG_LIBS = -L. -lmagic -lregex -lshlwapi

all: $(SHLIB)
$(SHLIB): libmagic.a libregex.a

LIBMAGIC =libmagic/apprentice.o \ 
[... many object files ...]
libmagic.a: $(LIBMAGIC)

LIBREGEX = libgnurx/regex.o
libregex.a: $(LIBREGEX)
```

Note that I do not tell `make`how to build a static library, leaving that to the automatic rules. That way there are no issues with `ar` missing. Note that the Linux/Mac OSX build uses a system installed library.

I think RcppGSL is not a good comparison in your case, since it uses an external library on *all* platforms. Reason is that with this package it has to be possible to compile and link with GSL *after* package installation. In your case, all the compilation and linking is done at installation time, right?

Comment: RcppGSL uses an _external_ library on all OSs.  Per an old convention, CRAN has it on Windows as well and points to it via `GSL_LIBS`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel RcppGSL also *needs* an external library, as otherwise only the few functions defined in the package like `fastLm` would be available, right?

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote six minutes. RcppGSL uses an _external_ library _on all platforms_ and never builds GSL itself.  That is similar to other packages using GSL on CRAN. For Windows, they all rely on the environment variable GSL_LIBS.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I modified `Makevars.win` (https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/blob/master/src/Makevars.win). I was able to compile the package on Windows and submitting the package on Win Builder gives the happy message - `packaged installation of 'Rcppsbmod' as Rcppsbmod_0.1.0.zip
* DONE (Rcppsbmod)
In R CMD INSTALL`. There is still some work remaining - `No examples, no tests, no vignettes
* DONE
Status: 1 WARNING, 1 NOTE`, but that's a story for some other day. Thank you to Ralf and Dirk for their inputs.

Comment: Regarding `GSL_LIBS`, I think this link - (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ThirdPartySoftware.html), gives a list of libraries which are available on CRAN and can be pointed towards. I am excited by the fact that `LIB_SBML` is available, not sure if it is built with a recent version of `SBML` though. Can we find out which version of underlying C library is available (and request it to be updated if it is built from an old version)?